# CSS Overlay not allowing DIv on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

Hey all I am having an issue with trying to set a div **on top** of the full screen overlay.

For some reason its not going over the top of the overlay - even when set to a **higher z-index** than the overlay itself.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/q56qvbha/2/) example. The **HELLO!** should be **on top** of the overlay but it is not:

JS:

```
var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"> </div>');

overlay.appendTo(document.body);
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 10000;
}

#tester {
  z-index: 2001;
}
```

HTML:

```
Lots of text to create scrollbars Lots of text to create scrollbars Lots of text to create
scrollbars Lots of text to create scrollbars......<div id="tester">HELLO!</div>.......Lots
of text to create scrollbars
```

Comment: `z-index` has no effect unless the element is also positioned, i.e. a position other than `static`

Comment: revised fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q56qvbha/3/

Comment: position can be 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed'

Comment: @SPlatten, or `sticky`

Comment: @Micheal_B, depends where you are getting your information from: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @SPlatten, I wouldn't rely on w3schools as an authoritative reference. It may be a good site for learning basic concepts, but for accurate and official references you should see W3C documentation. https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#pos-sch